# Excessive indirect references in NAME formula

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I am trying to read in an 'xls' files in python using pandas. My code basically is a one-liner:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(str("/test/test_file.xls"))
```

This code works for the majority of the files, but there are cases when it fails with the error:

```
Excessive indirect references in NAME formula
```

What I tried so far:

1. Tried changing the stack limit(panic and warning) to as far as 10000 in the Pandas package itself, where the exception was occurring. A recursion limit was encountered, so raised it as far as 125000, which led to my Mac/Python reaching its limit so I am guessing not the right solution.
2. Used a memory-intensive EMR to see if it can read the file - nope.
3. Looked at the GitHub repo for XLRD [here](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) to raise a bug only to find out it's out of support.
4. Opened the file, saved it as an xlsx, used the same code to read it into a dataframe. Worked like a charm.
5. Tried using [Spark Excel Library](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) to read in a particular section of the data - this worked too but I need to use pandas.
6. Googled it only to find out the results would show me the XLRD code where the exception is defined. Not one person has reported it.
7. Tried using Python2 and Python3 with the latest and older versions of Pandas - no use.

I cannot share the file, but has anyone faced this issue before? Can someone help? All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You might not be able to share the file, but you should be able to create a simple, sharable example. Without that, folks are left guessing what's going wrong. It sounds like the problem is formulae with references (but that's just a guess). Try creating a minimal sheet with just a formula or two to see if that triggers the problem. If so, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open the xls file
2. Copy/paste all cells as values
3. Rerun your script

Hard to help further without having access to the file to explain exactly what is happening.

But chances are xlrd is trying to resolve the value of a formula and is exceeding the "STACK_PANIC_LEVEL".  Without seeing the formula, very difficult to say more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try to copy-paste, the formulas get pasted, not the values. I changed the stack trace and recursion limit to a very high number and still, I was facing the issue. As I do not know which column creates the issue, I don't know which formula it is either. Also, I am looking for a programmatic approach, if it was manual then I could just save it as xlsx and it would be read fine.

Comment: To add on, I tried copy-pasting as values, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Copy the cells.  Right click and choose "paste special".  Select "Values" and click ok.  That will remove the formulas.  Also, save and exit the file before executing your script.

Comment: Tried after saving as values and exiting, still the same issue.

Comment: Unless you can provide a file that replicates the issue, there isn't much more I can do.  Sorry.  Best bet may be to add some logging to the xlrd source code before where the exception is thrown.  May point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot do that. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

xlrd has a method of `evaluate_name_formula()`. When you try to open a .xls file with xlrd, it will raise an error (as you described) if your file has many user-defined formulas. To try to solve your problem, I think you can delete these user-defined formulas and keep the file free of these formulas. Or you can try to edit xlrd code, and prevent it from raising the Error, which seems much more difficult.

Comment: I did try removing the formulas from the file and was still facing the issue. Tried the other solution too but as you mentioned, it was really hard so had to look for alternatives.